# How do I get my cheesecake bottom not to crumble?

Tags: baking, cake, chocolate

I made a triple chocolate cheesecake. The bottom is just crushed Oreos (no filling) and melted butter which is baked to make the crust.

But once I was done making the cheesecake and tried to serve it, the crust is sufficiently crumbly that it like leaves a trail every time I serve it.

## My Question

Is there a way to reduce how crumbly the crust is?

I don't need it to be perfectly congealed, but I'd like it to not get everywhere when I serve it and so a more congealed crust would be preferable.

Comment: How tightly did you pack it when you made the cheesecake? I find that crumb crusts need to be packed very well in order to hold together when serving.

Comment: I applied a fair amount of force when pushing it down flattening it. I mean, it could be an issue of not packing enough. Perhaps I don't efficiently or correctly apply force to smooth and pack it. But I don't think it's that because I have a different cheesecake recipe that uses graham crackers and I don't have this issue with that one. I'm not quite sure why the Oreo crust doesn't stick together.

Comment: What's the butter to cookie ratio?  Depending on what cookies I crumble, I sometimes add more butter for this reason.  Also, do you bake the crust before adding the cheesecake?

Comment: Yes, I bake it before hand. 2 cups Oreos 3 Tbsp butter. Baked at 350°F for ~ 8 min

Comment: Some recipes add some sugar to the butter. That can make it stickier (even to the point of toffee holding the biscuit together, which is going too far).

Comment: I've always seen Oreo crusts using whole Oreos then putting them through the food processor.  I think it needs the filling (or a sugar) to help bind it.

Comment: @Brooke ok, maybe I will try that next time. I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2):

When you crumble the Oreos for the Oreo crust, keep the fillings in. You can put them all in a plastic bag and squash them thoroughly with a rolling pin, then scrape the whole (somewhat greasy) mass out and press it into your cheesecake pan. That one ingredient -whole Oreos- is all you need for the crust.

Comment: That's a good point -- the centers are fat & sugar, so you already have the fat you need.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying a mixture of graham crackers and Oreo. You'll still get the flavor of the Oreo, and you'll also have the graham cracker as a binding agent.